# How to enable console.logs in NEXTJS production

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

Folks, I'm trying to implement an integration between nextjs and firebase. The thing is, it takes forever for the project to build, my router is not working. How do I allow my console.logs to be displayed in production environment? I've added

```
optimization: {
      minimize: false,
    },
```

to my `nextConfig` to no avail. What's the problem here? Is it webpack, nextjs or firebase that suppresses console.logs?

My deps are:

```
"firebase": "^10.7.2",
"firebase-admin": "^11.11.1",
"next": "12.2.5",
"react": "^17.0.2",
```

I'm using firebase deploy in order to deploy it.